# gpg-agent doesn't background

Tags: windows, gnupg, gpg4win, gpg-agent

Maybe I am misunderstanding, but when I launch `gpg-agent`, it never goes into the background.

```
$ gpg-agent --daemon --verbose
gpg-agent[16136]: listening on socket `C:\Users\OliverSalzburg\AppData\Roaming\gnupg\S.gpg-agent'
gpg-agent[16136]: listening on socket `C:\Users\OliverSalzburg\AppData\Roaming\gnupg\S.gpg-agent.ssh'
gpg-agent[16136]: gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.0.30 started
gpg-agent[16136]: DBG: returning notify handle 000000D0
gpg-agent[16136]: putty message loop thread 0x2378 started
```

The terminal will just be stuck at that point until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is this under Cygwin, WSL, or using the native builds?

Comment: @grawity I'm using Gpg4win.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue, I don't know if this is a workaround or the actual way to go, but you can run

```bash
gpg-connect-agent /bye
```